# Error al comparar dos strings en un if en twig

Tags: string, condiciones, twig

Tengo un error al comparar dos `strings` en `twig`.

Aquí está un ejemplo de mi código:

```
{% set var1 = "" %}
{% set var2 = "" %}
{% for unidad in array %}
    {% if unidad.var1 == var1 %}
        {% if unidad.var2 == var2 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ habitacion.var1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ habitacion.var2 }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr><td>---</td><td>---</td></tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td>|{{ unidad.var1 }}| |{{ var1 }}|</td>
            <td>|{{ unidad.var2 }}| |{{ var2 }}|</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% set var1 = unidad.var1 %}
    {% set var2 = unidad.var2 %}
{% endfor %}
```

El problema es que el bucle no entra en el `if`, siendo las dos variables iguales en algunos casos. Os muestro la pantalla de salida en una vuelta del bucle que no entra en el `if`:

```
<td>|NORMAL| |NORMAL|</td>
<td>|311| |311|</td>
```

He probado tambien a poner el `if` de esta forma:

```
{% if unidad.var1 is same as(var1) %}
```

Pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿A qué `if` te refieres, al primero o al segundo?

Comment: Ninguno de los dos funciona, lo que muestro por pantalla es el primero @fedorqui

Comment: Por curiosidad, `var1` y `var2` se asignan al final... Al primer ciclo del `for` nunca entra en ninguna de las condiciones... Y al asignarlas al final, asignas el valor actual de `unidad.var1` y `unidad.var2` por lo que creo que si son diferentes, nunca va a entrar en un `if`... ¿O si?

Comment: Se asigna al final porque comparo los valores con la vuelta anterior, por lo que la primera vez nunca va a entrar @NaCl

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una teoría al respecto, puede ser que en algunas de los reemplazos el valor de unidad.var1 y unidad.var2 sea false o null o algo similar?

Recuerda que twig se comporta muy parecido a PHP así que si comparas un string con false significa que no hay string así que daría falso y no te mostraría esta fila.

Puedes agregar algunos datos de ejemplo?

saludos